# Cancel download in DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am trying to download images from an URL using the following code :-

```
public static void writeToDisk(Context context, @NonNull String imageUrl, @NonNull String downloadSubfolder) {
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);
    String fileName = imageUri.getPath();
    String downloadSubpath = downloadSubfolder + fileName;

    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(imageUri);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDescription(imageUrl);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setDestinationUri(getDownloadDestination(downloadSubpath));

    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

I cant figure out how to cancel the download once it's started.

Answer (score 13):

Use the `enqueue` method the get the `ID` as in

```
long downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

And, then use the `remove` method passing the `downloadID` to it.

```
downloadManager.remove(downloadID);
```

Comment: when I try to do this, it gives me "java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()" at long downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy , I can't understand why you need to use `enqueue` method under AsyncTask, I think the error is appearing from there. If you really need that 1.you can pass a `Activity` to the `AsyncTask`'s constructor then you can use `Activity.runOnUiThread` or 2. you can use `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper).pose(Runnable...)`